# Unix Utitliy du -b vs du -h

Tags: unix

I was using the unix utility `du -h` to check the file sizes of a text and a utf file. The man page says the `-h --human-readable` flag "print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)". After reading the man page, I decided to try `du -b`. The man page says the `-b --bytes` flag is "equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'". What I understand is that `du -b` lists how many bytes are in the file.

The output of `du -b` is `122`, but when running `du -h` on the same file I get `4.0K`.

What does the `K` stand for? When looking at the man page it looks like it is supposed represent Kilobytes, but 122 bytes can't be 4 Kilobytes. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the block size?  It is very possible that a 122 byte file takes a 4K block on the disk (you can't put two files into the same block)   https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#:~:text=ext4%20allocates%20storage%20space%20in,time%20and%20typically%20is%204KiB.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help]/

Comment: I think understand now. This is an ext4 system that most likely was created with 4K per block. So to clarify, a block is a set amount of space where a file can be or the capacity, but a file's actual size can be smaller than a block.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here has to do with block size of your filesystem.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62049/why-is-a-text-file-taking-up-at-least-4kb-even-when-theres-just-one-byte-of-tex gives a good answer.

The gist is that many filesystems reserve disk space in 4 kilobyte chunks.  So, even if a file contains very few bytes of information, it'll take up 4K on the filesystem.

```
$ echo "foo" > foo
$ du -h foo
4.0K    foo
```

The number of bytes of the contents of the file may be far less than 4K, like 122 bytes, but the file itself is taking up 4K on your filesystem.

Comment: after all, it's named for "disk usage" not file size

Comment: Thanks for the response. My bad for posting on the wrong board.